# AOSP PackageManagerService referencing Roboelectric and therefore does not compile

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-source

I built AOSP 5.1.0_r3 and imported into IntelliJ. And followed [these steps.](https://newcircle.com/s/post/1720/aosp_sources_in_the_ide)

But When I open for example PackageManagerService.java code its not able to compile and its referencing external/robolectric/lib/main/android.jar/android/os/Process. For example SHELL_UID is missing:

```
private static final int SHELL_UID = Process.SHELL_UID;
```

If I look in standard android.jar the SHELL_UID [it's there](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java).
There are many more cases like this. What could be wrong here?

Screen1:
[image]

Screen2:
[image]

-----> UPDATE 2 FIXED ISSUES:

Added excluded-paths also found out that I had to delete the dependencies in the Project structure:

[image]

In PackageManagerService.java it still cant resolve symbol:

[image]

-----> UPDATE 2 OPEN ISSUES:

And in this Manifest (and others) it cant resolve several symbols (related to Android):
[image]

Comment: Your statement about Roboelectric is not clear. PackageManagerService does not have any references to it, and `SHELL_UID` is defined in `android.os.Process`. Perhaps show the exact error you are getting?

Comment: @Devunwired Updated. It's picking up an android.jar under roboelectric see picture. In here SHELL_UID is missing. But if you search in the standard code and I guess a standard android.jar it's there. So somehow it's using the wrong android.jar... or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a common problem I'm aware of, so I'm not entirely certain why you are seeing this error specifically. Regardless, to avoid the IDE getting confused, you could add `external/roboelectric` to a custom `excluded-paths` file so Idegen will ignore it in the generated IDE classpath.

If you don't already have one of these files, it goes in the top-level directory of your AOSP tree, and contains directories to exclude during generation. You can see the [built-in exclude file for example syntax](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/android-5.1.0_r3/tools/idegen/excluded-paths).

Idegen is supposed to exclude all JAR files, but it may only do that for files in `out/` and `prebuilts/`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I have some small bits not working... Appreciate if you could take a look, see UPDATE 2.